Create a dataset based on an ID and create columns for each corresponding date
I am trying to fathom what exactly is being asked by my management.
I have a MySQL 5.7 table that looks like this:
| email_id | source | message_id | submit_dt |
----------------------------------------------
|   id100  | google |   msg227   | 2024-11-12|
|   id200  | yahoo  |   msg227   | 2024-11-12|
|   id300  | google |   msg227   | 2024-11-12|
|   id100  | yahoo  |   msg227   | 2024-11-11|
|   id200  | google |   msg227   | 2024-11-11|
|   id300  | aol    |   msg227   | 2024-11-10|

I need to write a query that will take the above and make it look like this:
| email_id | submit_dt | source | message_id | submit_dt | source | message_id | repeat
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id100    | 2024-11-12| google |   msg227   | 2024-11-11| yahoo  |   msg227   | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id200    | 2024-11-12| yahoo  |   msg227   | 2024-11-11| google |   msg227   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id300    | 2024-11-12| google |   msg227   | 2024-11-10| aol    |   msg227   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So essentially, I need to line up up each email_id in a single row and repeat every list the date, source, and message_id associated with the email_id.
I hope that makes sense.
This is what I attempted to no avail:
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(`email_id`) AS 'Email ID'
  , `submit_dt`
  , `source` 
  , `message_id`
FROM `submissions` 
WHERE `message_id` LIKE '240227' GROUP BY `email_id` ORDER BY `submissions`.`email_id` ASC;

I am getting the below error:
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 
'righters_db.submissions.submit_dt' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I don't even think the query will produce what I'm trying to achieve.
Please help me solve this or advise if what I am trying to do cannot be done.

Can you change the sql_mode away from only_full_group_by, because that is what is stopping you?

You can't do this in MySQL 5.7, because it lacks window functions. You must either compromise on your choice of pivot-table format, or else upgrade to MySQL 8.0 or later.

It's called a "pivot". It's certainly possible in MySQL 5.7, but it might be simpler to do it in a spreadsheet.

@BillKarwin When you say compromise on your choice of pivot-table format, you are referring to Excel.  Is that right?

No, I'm referring to a pivot-table style of SQL query. You can view answers tagged with the [tag:pivot-table] tag here on Stack Overflow to see lots of examples. But the result you show isn't practical to implement on MySQL 5.7.

@BillKarwin On that note, I guess I'll just export the results to a CSV and create the pivot over there.  Thank you.

@JohnBeasley or just install myodbc and connect from excel to mysql directly and do the pivot that way in excel. Dynamic pivoting is not really suitable for sql as in sql you have to know the columns the query returns right upfront. You would need a minimum of two queries to achieve what you want. In mysql v5.7, you would have to use a hack with session variables to achieve what you want. The resulting code would not run in any later version of mysql as the hack is no longer available due to security considerations.

Technically this type of issue not possible. But if there're exactly two rows under email_id, then is can be possible through SQL query.
This is query to find exactly two records:
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email_id) AS email_index
FROM submissions
WHERE email_id IN (
  SELECT email_id 
  FROM ( 
      SELECT email_id,
         count(*) as count_email
      FROM submissions
      GROUP BY email_id
  ) T1
  WHERE count_email = 2
)
ORDER BY email_id ASC

This is final query where merged two records and show in a single row:
WITH submissions_f AS (
  SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email_id) AS email_index
  FROM submissions
  WHERE email_id IN (
    SELECT email_id 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT email_id,
           count(*) as count_email
        FROM submissions
        GROUP BY email_id
    ) T
    WHERE count_email = 2
  )
  ORDER BY email_id ASC
)
SELECT T1.email_id,
  T1.submit_dt, T1.source, T1.message_id, 
  T2.submit_dt, T2.source, T2.message_id,
  IF((T1.source LIKE T2.source) and (T1.message_id LIKE T2.message_id), true, '') as repeat_data

FROM (SELECT * FROM submissions_f WHERE email_index = 1) T1
  INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM submissions_f WHERE email_index = 2) T2
  ON T1.email_id = T2.email_id;

Output according to your expection:

db<>fiddle query for refference.
Please update your repeat_data column SQL Logic according to your expectation.
